# How does Redux change UI in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, redux

I've been trying hard to wrap my head around this concept but with no luck.
The official React tutorial is really good but for me it's way too complex and just simply a little bit too hard.

I'm trying to understand Redux and so far I can create actions, reducers, I  can dispatch an action and then see how the store state changes after dispatching it. I also managed to understand `connect` of react-redux and it works perfectly well and I'm able to trigger dispatches from any place in my app. So I think I almost got it figured out. Almost, because here's the elephant in the room - I dispatch the action, I see the Redux state change but HOW DO I CHANGE THE UI?

For example I have `text` object in my initial state with value `Initial text` and once a button is clicked I want to change the text to `Clicked text` and DISPLAY the text somewhere in the UI (let's say on the button).

How do I "access" the Redux state in React and how do I dynamicaly change it?

It seems to be very simple without React, e.g..: https://jsfiddle.net/loktar/v1kvcjbu/ - `render` function handles everything, I understand everything that happens here.

But on the other side "todo" from official React+Redux tutorial looks like this: https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html , it's so sophisticated I have no idea where to look.

The `Add Todo` button submits a form that dispatches `dispatch(addTodo(input.value))` action. The action itself does nothing just increases the ID and passes the text to the store and the reducer just returns the new state. Then how the todo is being rendered on the page? Where? I'm lost at this point. Maybe there are simpler tutorials, I'd love to have an one-button Redux tutorial it still can be complicated with multiple layers of components :(

I suspect the magic happens in TodoList.js as they're mapping over something there but still I have no idea where todos come from there, and what it has to do with Redux (there's no simple reducer/action/dispatch in that file).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look into `mapStateToProps` function, thats the last piece you are missing. It updates the props of your component from the redux state, thus triggering a rerender when your state changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the confusion you have is that part of [reducer composition](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html) and [selectors](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html).

Let's look at it in a reverse order, from the UI back.

**In the connected component** [containers/VisibleTodoList.js](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#containersvisibletodolistjs) it gets the `todos` from the "state" (the global store object of `redux`) inside `mapStateToProps`, while passing it through the `getVisibleTodos` method.
Which can be called a selector, as it selects and returns only a portion of the data that it receives:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { toggleTodo } from '../actions'
import TodoList from '../components/TodoList'

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
    default:
      return todos
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: id => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}

const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)

export default VisibleTodoList
```

**The `state` (redux store)** that passed to `mapStateToProps` came from     the root reducer [reducers/index.js](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#reducersindexjs) and is actually a single       reducer (object) that represent the combination of all other reducers    via the `combineReducers` utility of `redux`:

```
  import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
  import todos from './todos'
  import visibilityFilter from './visibilityFilter'

  const todoApp = combineReducers({
    todos,
    visibilityFilter
  })

  export default todoApp
```

As you can see, the `todos` reducer is there. so that's why inside    the `mapStateToProps` we call it like this `state.todos`.

Here is the [reducers/todos.js](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#reducerstodosjs):

```
const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
          text: action.text,
          completed: false
        }
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(todo =>
        (todo.id === action.id) 
          ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed}
          : todo
      )
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default todos
```

On each action of type `'ADD_TODO'` it will return a new state with the new `todo`:

```
case 'ADD_TODO':
          return [
            ...state,
            {
              id: action.id,
              text: action.text,
              completed: false
            }
          ]
```

This the the action creator for it inside [actions/index.js](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#action-creators):

```
let nextTodoId = 0
export const addTodo = text => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}
```

So here is the full flow of `redux` (i omitted the button that calls the action as i assume this is obvious part for you).
Well, almost a full flow, none of this could have happened without the `Provider` HOC that wraps the `App` and inject the store to it in [index.js](https://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html#indexjs):

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import todoApp from './reducers'
import App from './components/App'

let store = createStore(todoApp)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Now when the `redux` `state` changes, a call to `mapStateToProps` is invoked that will return the new mapped `props`. `connect` will pass those new `props` and this will trigger a new `render` call (actually the entire react life cycle flow) to the connected component.
This way the UI will be re-rendered with the fresh new data from the store.

Answer (score 1):

connect is typically used to connect react component and  Redux state.connect  is a higher order component. The  component which are using connect function are wrapped inside it. The method signature is
connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])
mapStateToProps has access to redux state and mapDispathToProps has access to store.dispatch. All the props are merged and passed as props to underlying component. Redux has only single state of truth. store that is passed as a props to Provider components has a method called store.getState().

So , keep one thing in mind react components are data driven . Data derives UI. React components rerender only when state is changed or props have been modified. you make change in any of two , components goes through various life cycle methods.